# How do you determine a 2nd, 3rd, 4th, up to nth value in a range / How do you exclude a value from a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to find an nth value in a range using excel. I'm not very tech-savvy but I have a basic understanding of the formulas and how to use them. I tried

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A10<D1, [MAX(A1:A10-D1)])
```

because I thought it said "If A1:A10 is lesser than D1, use A1:A10 without the value of D1 as a range and then find the maximum of that range." but it needs a third result, [result_if_false}. I already have a way to find the MAX and the MIN but I just need help with finding an nth value or excluding a value from a range. Thank you!

A1:A10 is the range of numbers

D1 is the Highest number or the MAX of the range

D1:D10 is where I'm planning to show the ordered numbers

Comment: Try using `LARGE` or `AGGREGATE` Function.

Comment: So you may try anyone of these in cell `D1` & Fill Down --> • `=LARGE($A$1:$A$10,ROW(A1))` or • `=AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$1:$A$10,ROW(A1))`

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share a screenshot of your expected output, i assume you might want to exclude `D1` value or something

Comment: Use large() and for min() small().

Answer (score 0):

In cell D1, paste the following formula:

```
=LARGE($A$1:$A$10,COUNT($A$1:$A$10)-COUNT($A1:$A$10)+1)
```

Then copy and paste it into cells D2:D10.